# How to handle an immutable table referencing mutable tables?

Tags: database, database-design

In making a pretty standard online store in .NET, I've run in to a bit of an architectural conundrum regarding my database. I have a table "Orders", referenced by a table "OrderItems". The latter references a table "Products".
Now, the orders and orderitems tables are in most aspects immutable, that is, an order created and its orderitems should look the same no matter when you're looking at the tables (for instance, printing a receipt for an order for bookkeeping each year should yield the same receipt the customer got at the time of the order).
I can think of two ways of achieving this behavior, one of which is in use today:
1. Denormalization, where values such as price of a product are copied to the orderitem table.
2. Making referenced tables immutable. The code that handles products could create a new product whenever a value such as the price is changed. Mutable tables referencing the products one would have their references updated, whereas the immutable ones would be fine and dandy with their old reference

What is your preferred way of doing this? Is there a better, more clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. I'm writing on a quite complex enterprise software that includes a kind of document management and auditing and is used in pharmacy.

Normally, primitive values are denormalized. For instance, if you just need a current state of the customer when the order was created, I would stored it to the order.

There are always more complex data that that need to be available of almost every point in time. There are two approaches: you create a history of them, or you implement a revision control system, which is almost the same.

The history means that every state that ever existed is stored as a separate record, in the same or another table.

I implemented a revision control system, where I split records into two tables, one for the actual item, lets say a product, and the other one for its versions. This way I can reference the product as a whole, or any specific version of it, because both have its own primary key.

This system is used for many entities. I can safely reference an object under revision control from audit trail for instance or other immutable records. At the beginning it seems to be more complex to have such a system, but at the end it is very straight forward and solves many problems at once.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the price in both the Product table and the OrderItem table is NOT denormalizing if the price can change over time. Normalization rules say that every "fact" should be recorded only once in the database. But in this case, just because both numbers are called "price" doesn't make them the same thing. One is the current price, the other is the price as of the date of the sale. These are very different things. Just like "customer zip code" and "store zip code" are completely different fields; the fact that both might be called "zip code" for short does not make them the same thing. Personally, I have a strong aversion to giving fields that hold different data the same name because it creates confusion. I would not call them both "Price": I would call one "Current_Price" and the other "Sale_Price" or something like that.

Not keeping the price at the time of the sale is clearly wrong. If we need to know this -- which we almost surely do -- than we need to save it.

Duplicating the entire product record for every sale or every time the price changes is also wrong. You almost surely have constant data about a product, like description and supplier, that does not change every time the price changes. If you duplicate the product record, you will be duplicating all this data, which definately IS denormalization. This creates many potential problems. Like, if someone fixes a spelling error in the product description, we might now have the new record saying "4-slice toaster" while the old record says "4-slice taster". If we produce a report and sort on the description, they'll get separated and look like different products. Etc.

If the only data that changes about the product and that you care about is the price, then I'd just post the price into the OrderItem record.

If there's lots of data that changes, then you want to break the Product table into two tables: One for the data that is constant or whose history you don't care about, and another for data where you need to track the history. Like, have a ProductBase table with description, vendor, stock number, shipping weight, etc.; and a ProductMutable table with our cost, sale price, and anything else that routinely changes. You probably also want an as-of date, or at least an indication of which is current. The primary key of ProductMutable could then be Product_id plus As_of_date, or if you prefer simple sequential keys for all tables, fine, it at least has a reference to product_id. The OrderItem table references ProductMutable, NOT ProductBase. We find ProductBase via ProductMutable.

Answer (score 0):

I think Denormalization is the way to go.

Also, Product should not have price (when it changes from time to time & when price mean different value to different people -> retailers, customers, bulk sellers etc).

You could also have a price history table where it contains ProductID, FromDate, ToDate, Price, IsActive - to maintain the price history for a product.